# Dash (-) in anonymous class member

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

is it possible to use dash (-) in a member name of an anonymous class? I'm mainly interested in this to use with asp.net mvc to pass custom attributes to html-helpers, since I want my html to pass html5-validation, this starting with data-.

Exemple that doesn't work:

```
<%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Something, new {data-animal = "pony"})%>
```

Putting a @ in front of the member name doesn't do the trick either.

Update: If this isn't possible, is there a recommended way todo what I want? My current temporary solution is to add a replace to the whole thing like this:

```
<%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Something, new {data___animal = "pony"}).Replace("___", "-")%>
```

But that sucks, because it's ugly and will break when `Model.Something` contains three underscores. Buhu.

Comment: Your workaround doesn't work in all scenarios: Html.DroppableZone(Zones.Left).WrapIn("div", new { @data-role = "collapsible"}).Render(); does not return a string over which one can replace anything :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use - as part of any identifier.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(VS.71).aspx

Comment: This answer is true but incomplete. There's a workaround. Please see my answer on this question.

Answer (score 26):

Just found this post while searchching for the same problem.

I found this link:
http://blogs.planetcloud.co.uk/mygreatdiscovery/post/Using-custom-data-attributes-in-ASPNET-MVC.aspx

It resolves the problem. It mentions the following:

> [...] or better yet, just use code from ASP.NET MVC source:

```
public static RouteValueDictionary AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(object htmlAttributes)
{
    RouteValueDictionary result = new RouteValueDictionary();
    if (htmlAttributes != null)
    {
        foreach (System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor property in System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(htmlAttributes))
        {
            result.Add(property.Name.Replace('_', '-'), property.GetValue(htmlAttributes));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: From the link: "Fortunately a solution for this was added in ASP.NET MVC 3 so that you can use an underscore instead which will be automatically converted to a hyphen."

Comment: You don't have to do this as @joelsand said. More here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9444822/245495

Comment: Well that sucks if you want to use an underscore.

Answer (score 17):

Collecting the Asp-Mvc version specific ways to do data- here:

MVC 3+  : Use an underscore _ and it will be automatically replaced by mvc 
 
MVC 1?,2: see @Jean-Francois answer, which points to [this](http://blogs.planetcloud.co.uk/mygreatdiscovery/post/Using-custom-data-attributes-in-ASPNET-MVC.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

No, because the dash is a C# operator ([minus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wch5w409.aspx)), and white space isn't significant.

Right now the compiler thinks you are trying to subtract `animal` from `data`, which doesn't work unless the `-` operator is specified for the types in question.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use the hyphen character.  You need to use alphanumeric characters, underscores, or the other characters described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(VS.71).aspx).  `'-'` is treated as a minus.  `data-animal` would be treated the same as `data - animal`, so that won't even compile unless you have separately defined `data` and `animal` (and it could present subtle bugs if you have!).

Edit: With C#'s capability to have identifiers with Unicode escape sequences, you can get the effect of a dash in an identifier name.  The escape sequence for "&mdash" (the longer dash character) is ["U+2014"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm).  So you would express data-animal as `data\u2014animal`.  But from a coding style point of view, I'm not sure why you wouldn't choose a more convenient naming convention.

Also, another point to highlight from "2.4.2 Identifiers (C#)": You can't have two of these escape sequences back to back in an identifier (e.g. `data\u2014\u2014animal`).

Comment: The naming convention is from HTML5; http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data

Comment: Ps yeah, \u2014 is like eh not optimal.

Comment: \u002d is the hyphen character.  When I saw "dash" in the question, I thought of the "&mdash" character first.

Comment: @svinto: You're right, \u2014 is not optimal.  I was just pointing out that you can in fact use it in an identifier if you want the dash character.  That said, even if you did have a way to make these \u* identifiers more human-readable, they would look the same as the characters ('-', etc.) that aren't allowed in identifiers (unless the syntax was highlighted differently, but admittedly I am not well-versed in that).

Comment: Nope... new { @data\u002drole = "collapsible"} does not compile.