# How to specify data attributes in razor, e.g., data-externalid="23151" on @this.Html.CheckBoxFor(...)

Tags: c#, .net, razor

```
@this.Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MyModel.MyBoolProperty, new { @class="myCheckBox", extraAttr="23521"})
```

With razor, I'm unable to specify values for data- attributes such as `data-externalid="23521"`

Is there a way to do this using `@this.Html.CheckBoxFor(...)`?

Answer (score 286, accepted):

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(
    m => m.MyModel.MyBoolProperty, 
    new { 
        @class = "myCheckBox", 
        data_externalid = "23521"
    }
)
```

The `_` will automatically be converted to `-` in the resulting markup:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="MyModel.MyBoolProperty" data-externalid="23521" class="myCheckBox" />
```

And that's true for all Html helpers taking a `htmlAttributes` anonymous object as argument, not only the `CheckBoxFor` helper.

Comment: wow, I can see the '_'  '-' conversion being really confusing... especially if someone does a string search looking for a given data attribute.  Is there another way?

Comment: Just transform this:   new { data_test="true"})   ->   new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data-test", "true" } });

Comment: And if you need the value to come from your ViewModel; `new { @class = "myCheckBox", data_externalid = Model.ExternalId }` I came looking for help on this topic and this was what I needed. :)

Comment: Over 8 years later this answer has just helped me out massively. I couldn't work out why adding my vue form v-model tag wouldn't work. I had to use v_model="blah" instead.