# Razor input element custom attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi I need to do the following:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Login, 
                 new { 
                       @class = "form-control", 
                       @placeholder = "Username", 
                       required="true" data-required-message="Please insert your name" 
                     })
```

But Im getting error on `data-required-message` seems that I can't use "-".

> Any clue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify data attributes in razor, e.g., data-externalid="23151" on @this.Html.CheckBoxFor(...)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444805/how-to-specify-data-attributes-in-razor-e-g-data-externalid-23151-on-this)

Answer (score 6):

You have to use it with underscore `_` and razor will render it as `-` in html:

```
data_required_message="Please insert your name"
```

another thing to note is that you don't need to put `@` sign in front of every parameter of `htmlAttributes` , we put it for `class` becasue `class` is a reserved word in **c#**, so it cannot be used directly as a variable name.

your final code will be like:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Login, 
                 htmlAttributes: new { 
                                       @class = "form-control",
                                       placeholder = "Username",
                                       required="true",
                                       data_required_message="Please insert your name" 
                                     })
```

you are also missing a comma after `placeholder` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try `data_required_message` instead of `data-required-message`