# Unable to apply attributes to a checkBoxFor

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

right now I have a checkbox that looks like this

```
<input type="checkbox" id="all@(part.ID)" class="part-class" data-partId="@(part.ID)" checked>
```

But it would be beneficial to me to instead convert this checkbox into a CheckBoxFor, so this is what I tried

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Parts[i].MoveAll, new { @id = all@"(part.ID)", @class="part-class", data-partId="@(part.ID)" })
```

But there are red line errors under id and data-partId attributes so how I'm confused on how to apply the same attributes to the checkboxFor?

Comment: Why did you use "all" in `all@"(part.ID)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the html attribute `data-partId` to `data_partId`. You can refer the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444805/how-to-specify-data-attributes-in-razor-e-g-data-externalid-23151-on-this). And also modified the dynamic id part.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Parts[i].MoveAll, new { @id = "all" + "@part.ID", @class = "part-class", data_partId = "@part.ID" })
```